# Vagrant and AppEngine Development Not Syncing Files

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, vagrant

I'm a new Vagrant user and I setup a Vagrant box to do AppEngine development on Windows (based on the 'hashicorp/precise32' image). It is working except for when I make file changes from windows. The file changes get synced, but the dev_appserver.py script does not recognize the file updates. It works ok when I edit locally on the box or when I restart the dev_appserver.py script manually.

I haven't tried Django, but it is the same concept.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this type of scenario outside the scope of Vagrant?

Comment: Why are you deploying to app engine with vagrant? Seems like overkill. Regardless, you might try using a Linux image instead. We've encountered Windows-only errors at times.

Comment: Actually it is a linux image (Ubuntu Precise), the client is Windows. Maybe I'll try another distro. Yeah I know it does sound like overkill, but I am handing off a large development project that's part appengine, part django. I didn't want to waste any time setting up the new developer's machine (or writing documentation :) ).

Comment: actually, it totally makes sense to have a replicable environment. That said, is the Windows client running appcfg.py or is the Linux box doing it?

Comment: The virtual Linux box is running the script (dev_appserver.py).

Comment: I have the same problem :/ one solution is to use rsync but you will be going through hoops to get it to work, and rsync is slower than shared folder

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vagrant and Google App Engine are not syncing files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25217223/vagrant-and-google-app-engine-are-not-syncing-files)

Answer (score 1):

Using the latest appengine, you can use this to make it work.

```
dev_appserver.py --use_mtime_file_watcher=True
```