# Vagrant and Google App Engine are not syncing files

Tags: python, google-app-engine, vagrant

I am currently using Vagrant to spin up a VM to run GAE's dev_appserver in the Virtual Machine.

The sync folder works and I can see all the files.

But, after I run the dev appserver, changes to python files by the host machine are not dynamically updated.

To see updates to my python files, I have to relaunch dev appserver in my Virtual Machine.

Also, I have grunt tasks that watch html/css files. These also do not sync properly when updated by editors outside the Virtual Machine.

I suspect that it's something to do with the way Vagrant syncs files changed on the host machine.

Has anyone found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the answer!

In the latest version of google app engine, there is a new parameter you can pass to dev_appserver.py.

using `dev_appserver.py --use_mtime_file_watcher=True` works!

Although the change takes 1-2 seconds to detect, but it still works!